# AccessViolationException thrown on Navigate to Xamarin Forms Page

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I am trying to Navigate to a Xamarin Forms NavigationPage. However I am trying to do it after the Frame has been first loaded up with some "native" UWP pages.

```
this.rootFrame.Navigate(page.GetType(), param);
```

This code results in a `AccessViolationException`. The page object is a Xamarin.Forms.Page but I have also tried it with a NavigationPage(page) wrapper.

I realise that normal XF navigation is done with Navigation.PushAsync etc but I am at a point where the XF application and navigation infrastructure as not yet been initialised.

This is how I create my initial NavigationPage

```
XFormsApp.MainPage = new NavigationPage(contentPage);

var converter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationSerializer>();
var requestText = converter.Serializer.SerializeObject(request);

_rootFrame.Navigate(mainPage.GetType(), requestText);
```

I am trying to create a hybrid UWP app that starts with Native Pages and later  launches some XF Pages. The official [Xamarin Forms samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms) have an example of this for iOS and Android

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to Navigate to a Xamarin Forms NavigationPage. However I am trying to do it after the Frame has been first loaded up with some "native" UWP pages.
>
> `this.rootFrame.Navigate(page.GetType(), param);`
>
> This code results in a AccessViolationException. The page object is a Xamarin.Forms.Page but I have also tried it with a NavigationPage(page) wrapper.

The type of the first parameter in the `rootFrame.Navigate` method is [`forms:WindowsPage`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Tablet/WindowsPage.cs). But in your code you have used `ContentPage` where under `Xamarin.Forms` namespace as the first parameter, it is not a WindowsPage. So it would throw exception.

You could not navigate to Xamarin Forms Page in native client project. Because the page used is different in the Xamarin.Forms and UWP. The page is inherited `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` in uwp, and it is inherited [`TemplatedPage`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ContentPage.cs).

> I am trying to create a hybrid UWP app that starts with Native Pages and later launches some XF Pages. The official Xamarin Forms samples have an example of this for iOS and Android.

For your requirement, you could use the [`DependencyService`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to achieve that go back from `ContentPage` to `WindowsPage`. For more detail please refer to the following code .

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();

 }

 private void MyBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     LoadApplication(new App65.App());
 }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml(Portable)**

```
<StackLayout>
   <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
      VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
   <Button Text="GoBack"  Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**GoBackImplementation.cs**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GoBackImplementation))]

namespace App65.UWP
{
    public class GoBackImplementation : IGoBack
    {
        public void GoBack()
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame != null)
            {
                rootFrame = new Frame();
                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            }
        }

        private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have upload [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App65.git) to git hub. Please check.

Comment: "The type of the first parameter in the rootFrame.Navigate method is forms:WindowsPage" That is not correct. The type is "System.Type". Passing a NavigationPage as the Type is exactly how MVVMCross does its "All UWP" app which you can see here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Forms/Example001XAML. See the Presenter.Your DependenmcyService approach will not work with MVVMCross and even if it did I don't think that "going back" is my requirement

Comment: Perhaps my description is unclear.  The type is [`sourcePageType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#remarks) rather than `System.Type`.  So that when you passed `Xamarin.page`  with  NavigationPage(page) wrapper, it will throw exception.

Comment: If that is correct "Do you know why it is throwing an Exception and why would it be AccessViolationException raher than something like InvalidArgumentException. However and more importantly passing a NavigationPage type as the first argument is exactly how it works in MVVMCross. See this line https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-Forms/MvvmCross.Forms.Uwp/Presenters/MvxFormsUwpPagePresenter.cs#L30. I'd create you a simpler repro but my environment is currently screwed